# Loadrunner not taking unique values from parameter list

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am running loadrunner to test the my API. However with concurrent users (Vusers = 100) I am getting the error that "test aborted due to lack of parameters). When I checked the log I see that some of the member Ids in the file (parameterized in script) are not used at all and even some of them are duplicated. I want that loadrunner would select unique values for each hit and not repeat any value.

The scenario parameters

1. VuGen Script contains my request to the API, with 2 parameterized components. i.e member IDs and date.
2. Member IDs 100,000 ids supplied in the file.
3. Settings :
   a. Select next row: Unique
   b. Update value on: Each Iteration
   c. When out of values: Abort user
   d. Allocate 1000 values to each Vuser
   e. No. of Vuser (goal scenario) = 100
   f. Load generators = 2
   g. Test run time = 15mins
4. Load Runner version = 12.01

Comment: Actual error stack trace :

Error: Parameter 'member_id': No more unique values for this parameter in table 'member_id' [unique range is 2001-3000]. The Vuser is aborted according to "When Out Of Values" policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hard cut at fifteen minutes then not every user would have exhausted their block, as was the case with the virtual user message above - which should be expected when exhausting the data.

Alter your group execution policy to run until complete instead of running for a fixed duration.  This is likely the root of why you have some finish and some not.   As to the reuse, as this is by block size of number of rows, is there a chance of a repeating value in your 100K rows?   I would use Microsoft Logparser to run a quick count and then a count only where you have distinct values.  Should you see a difference in the two numbers then you have some repeating values....which would be pretty easy to have happen in a 100K value file.

Consider adding a third load generator (hardware matched) as a control group, running a single virtual user of each type.  If this control group runs clean, with fast response times, and the two other generators (presumably independent of the controller) show slower response times, then your difference in the control group will point to an overloaded generator.  Considering each one of your users is going to have a copy of that data file in RAM you may see a swap effect if any of the mdrv processes get swapped.   For some reason non of the performance testing tool vendors mark their code as non-swappable....

Comment: I altered my group policy to run for the complete duration. Still I get the same value.


 The 100K values file is set of distinct data fetched from a Oracle database so I do not think it is a repetitive. 

I even ran it on a single load generator with all the settings intact for 50 Vusers and then moved back till 10 Vusers. But it seems to reuse values from the file even though the settings dictate it to take unique values.

Any thing that I am missing?

Comment: Is re-use within a single user or across users?  Also, can you confirm that all of your infrastructure is running all the same release/patch level from controller through load generator, etc...   Expected behaviors for the system can get henky when you start crossing version streams

Comment: Let me make it a bit more clear. I have 2 load gens, and a 100K file of parameters, and a script in which the value is parameterized to accept from the file. In the script the parameter occurs only once. I am running 100Vusers and ideally I want that it should select unique values across both load gens i.e if one value from the file is used it should not be used again through out the load test.

Now to answer your question first the version throughout is 12.01.

I dont understand what do you mean by "Is re-use within a single user or across users?". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Two groups or one with multiple load generators?  Uniqueness is only guaranteed in the same group context

Comment: Multiple values are duplicated across both load generators. Even if I run with one load generator then also I see the duplication.
If you are asking from a Vuser's perspective, I don't know how we can find out if one single Vuser is taking a particular value all the time or not. However when I use the "Simulate" button in VUgen it shows unique values with my settings.
My question is that is there any settings which can guarantee me uniqueness when I run 100 VUsers to select unique values for each hit? One more question by group do you mean the block size?

Comment: Run with one load generator and one group to see if you get duplicates

Comment: I am new to loadrunner. Can you let me know what do you mean by 
"group"? Is it the block size?

Comment: When you create your scenario you assign a number of users to a script and a generator.  The uniqueness constraint is within the context of that group.

Comment: As you are new to LoadRunner you should have an expectation that your management will send you to training and provide you a mentor for a period of time to reach the state where you can operate independently.  The average Cosmetologist has 1500 hours of training and mentoring before they are on their own. You should expect at least that level of commitment from your management

Comment: I am using only one script and as you have suggested, i ran with one Load Generator also but still getting duplicate values. this times i have provided 900,000 values to the parameter file.

Comment: One Script.  One Load Generator.  One Group.   Then use Logparser with a select distinct to ensure that you have no duplicates in your data.

As to the size, keep in mind every user will have to load a copy of the data file into RAM for its own use.  It is not read from disk during the test because of the obvious conflicts of multiple user concurrent access and lock related issues.   Seek the smallest file/data set possible to meet your goals related to the use of resources per virtual user